# cannot find babel-runtime library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

When I am running yarn test:watch, I am getting this error.

```
    Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/toConsumableArray' from 'node_modules/pandas-js/dist/core/series.js'

Require stack:
  node_modules/pandas-js/dist/core/series.js
  node_modules/pandas-js/dist/core/index.js
  node_modules/pandas-js/dist/index.js

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/pandas-js/dist/core/series.js:8:27)
```

I tired

```
npm install --save-exact @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55
```

and then deleted node-modules folder and package-lock.json file and tried npm install again

That did not solve the issue too. Can anyone help me in this please.

This is the version of pandas-js library

```
"pandas-js": "^0.2.4",
```

in my package.json

Answer (score 1):

it works after I installed babel-cli, a lot of people have said this works for them @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55, but for me babel-cli helped.

Answer (score 0):

you can try simply deleting the node-modules folder from your project directory, and run `npm install` command can also use `yarn` to re-install the dependencies in your project